# Create Custom Registration Page In Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have been trying to add a new custom registration page for a different customer group. but i am not able to do it so far. what i am trying is summarized below :
 created a phtml file inside directory persistent/customer/form/seller.phtml
and defined its layout in local.xml
but when i am trying to call this file through my cms page a blank page is showing i don't know why. 
Seller.phtml is exact copy of register.phtml ,first just wanted to get that data then i will update it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of questions about Magento should go on magento.stackexchange.com